# What is this shadow in my photo?

Tags: troubleshooting, artifacts, ghosting

I'm pretty sure the subject didn't move, the shutter speed was ok @1/80s. I was using Canon 70D + 18-55mm IS STM and a built-in flash and shot in RAW. What it could be? What may be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is either subject motion or camera motion. 1/80 second is pretty slow for human subjects not making a specific effort to be still. It is also pretty slow to use hand held if you are going to pixel peep at 100% magnification.

The flash is much shorter in duration than the shutter, so the motion that is only illuminated by the ambient light is much dimmer than the light that came from the flash and froze the motion.

For more about how Av exposure mode with automatic flash exposure (TTL) works in many cameras including pretty much all Canon SLRs, please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46440/15871) to [How do I get my Canon 60D to use short shutter speeds with flash in Av mode?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46423/15871) as well as [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45566/15871) to [Why is flash TTL metering independent from ambient light metering?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/45455/15871)

The way Canon (as well as many other) cameras behave when using TTL flash with **Av** exposure mode is called *slow speed sync* or *dragging the shutter*. For more on *slow speed sync* please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/36211/15871) to [What is "Dragging the Shutter"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/36188/15871)

For more on how Canon's TTL automatic flash exposure systems works, please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/37732/15871) to [How do TTL flash metering systems calculate how much power is needed?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/37727/15871)

Comment: Oh, now I get it, the flash has been messing up my photos, I don't know why, for example, When I shot this picture I was in Av mode, why would the camera choose 1/80s shutter speed when there's so much light coming from the flash and it was sunny outside. Also I've noticed that when shooting in low light situations with flash, the camera chooses very slow shutter speeds, like I was shooting with no flash. I don't know why this is happening..

Comment: Please see http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46440/15871

Comment: And also http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/45455/15871

Comment: As well as http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/36211/15871